# Linq to Sql select from multiple table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, predicate

I have a question about selecting from multiple tables in C# using Linq.

Table structure is like this:

TABLE A 
TableAID
Column1
Column2

TABLE B 

 TableBID TableAID Column3 Column4

So in code i have:

```
List<string> myList = new List{"Test1","Test2"};
var myView = MYDC.TableA.AsQueryAble();
```

If I want to select records from table A using where on Column1, I would simply use:

```
myView = myView.Where(k=>myList.Contains(k.Column1));
```

But if I want to preserve the myView as queryable of TableA and if I want to use where on TableB on Column3, which is linked to TableA with a foreign key, how would I do it?

I tried the following with no success:

```
myView = myView.Where(k=>myList.Contains(k.TableB.Select(kk=>kk.Column3)));
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it mean “no success”? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It says:
Delegate 'System.Func<BusinessTransactions.DBML.t_TableA,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: I would point out that when you see a `Func` (vs an `Expression<Func<>>`) in a queryable statement, it usually means that it's running the predicate _in memory_ rather than translating out to a database call, so it often negates the queryable benefit (since you're returning the entire recordset in order to perform the predicate).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to to this. Here are two of them:

```
var q = (
    from b in MYDB.TableB
    where myList.Contains(b.Column3)
    select b.TableA).Distinct();

var q =
    from a in myView
    let bs = a.TableB.Where(b => myList.Contains(b.Column3))
    where bs.Any()
    select a;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I know how to do that using a normal linq query. But how about using predicates?